# Fn key results in slashes rather than brightness, etc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10. On 14.04, the Fn key controlled bits and pieces such as mute, brightness, volume, lock touchpad, etc. all worked fine.

After the upgrade, they don't. Pressing the Fn key post-upgrade results in a slash.

I've tried all the various options suggested elsewhere online to change grub's config:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Suffice to say, none solve the issue.

I've since wiped Ubuntu and replaced it with Linux Mint 17.1, which I believe is based on Ubuntu 14.04, the version in which everything worked.

This leads me to believe there is some sort of setup/configuration setting which was wiped by the upgrade and is the default in Mint and in Fedora too, of which I tried a live CD.

Hardware Info:
`$ sudo dmidecode | grep -A3 '^System Information'`:

```
System Information
  Manufacturer: Acer
  Product Name: Aspire V3-771
  Version: V2.08
```

At a bit of a loss with this.

---

xev output:

```
PropertyNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
    atom 0x13d (_NET_WM_STATE), time 1780436, state PropertyNewValue

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 1782161, (734,282), root:(736,363),
    state 0x10, keycode 106 (keysym 0xffaf, KP_Divide), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 1782257, (734,282), root:(736,363),
    state 0x10, keycode 106 (keysym 0xffaf, KP_Divide), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

ClientMessage event, serial 37, synthetic YES, window 0x3200001,
    message_type 0x12f (WM_PROTOCOLS), format 32, message 0x12d (WM_DELETE_WINDOW)
```

Comment: Run the program `xev` from a terminal and press the Fn+key chords. Copy-press the `KeyPress` paragraphs that appear on the terminal.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks. I've added the output now.

Comment: Ok, so this key is the keypad `/`. What does it do in a terminal? In GUI applications?

Comment: Except it's not. It's Fn. It just produces a slash. In any application

Comment: The fact it produces `/` makes me think something is misconfigured somewhere

Comment: That's a weird one: usually `Fn` is handled to some extent by the BIOS, and not seen at all by the OS (it only changes what the OS sees when you press another key). It could be ACPI-related. Maybe try fiddling [with the `acpi_osi` kernel parameter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28848/what-does-the-kernel-boot-parameter-set-acpi-osi-linux-do)?

Comment: I've already changed it to as many permeations as I could find. Nothing seems to work.